# User specific Validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

I am  attempting to create following rule:
    if Utiltiy (look up field) =  abc  then ONLY allow certain users to edit these date fields  date field1 and date field2.
Following rule doesnt work.....
***i logged in as user NOT specified in the following rule i was able to edit the date  fields. The rule should only allow users specified below should be able to edit the date fields.

```
AND(
    Utility__c = 'PREPA - PR',
    OR(
        ISCHANGED(Net_Meter_Agreement_Date__c),
        ISCHANGED(Received_Date__c)
    ),
    $User.Id  <> "005E00000050ir2",
    $User.Id  <> "005E0000006kdYD"
)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by "doesn't work."

Comment: Perhaps it is not a duplicate, but that post has some good advice for how to build a user specific validation that works *across environments*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Utility__r.Name = 'PREPA - PR'`. I'd recommend to create a hierarchial Custom Setting's checkbox field and assign `true` to the users you want to bypass this validation - any hardcoded Id is not good

Comment: I believe you mean `Utility__r.Name`?

Comment: Utility__c is lookup field and it should be selected utility=PREPA - PR

Comment: only certain users should be ab;e to edit the date fields if the lookup filed utility=PREPA - PR,

Comment: please let me know if i am specifying the Utility__c = 'PREPA - PR', incorrectly

Comment: @Suja lookup fields are storing Id value, they are just displayed as a name with hyperlink